# Interaction vs Association

Tags: regression, interaction, association-measure

1. What is the difference between interaction and association? (It would be great if someone explains it to me by a plot or example).
2. Can we have interaction between two continuous variables?
3. Also, do I need to bring the interaction among the variables into the model? if yes, Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Question 1

An association is just a relationship or correlation between two variables. For example, "the happier someone is, the healthier they are." Here are data and a plot that would look like this:

```
library(dplyr) # loading package
library(ggplot2) # loading package
set.seed(1839) # set seed for replication
x <- rnorm(200,10,1) # generating data for x
y <- x + rnorm(200,0,3) # y is predicted from x plus some residuals
data <- tibble(x, y) # make data frame
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) # plot
```

[image]

I always teach interactions as thinking about "it depends" associations. If I were to ask you if basketball fans are going to be happy if the Golden State Warriors win the title this year, you would have to say: "It depends." What does it depend on? It depends on *how much they like the Warriors*. That is, the effect of who wins on happiness *depends on how much they like the team.* This is an interaction. That example might look something like this:

```
# generating data for two conditions, one with a positive, and one with negative slope
set.seed(1839) # set seed for replication
cavs_win <- tibble(winner=factor(rep("cavs", 100), levels=c("cavs","warriors")), # generating data if cavs win
                   like_warriors=rnorm(100,0,1), # generating how much people like the warriors
                   happiness=-1*like_warriors + rnorm(100,0,3)) # happiness will be negatively predicted if cavs win
warriors_win <- tibble(winner=factor(rep("warriors", 100), levels=c("cavs","warriors")), # generating data if warriors win
                       like_warriors=rnorm(100,0,1), # generating how much people like the warriors
                       happiness=like_warriors + rnorm(100,0,3)) # happiness will be negatively predicted if cavs win

# combining two outcomes into one dataset
data <- cavs_win %>% 
  bind_rows(warriors_win)

lm(happiness ~ winner*like_warriors, data) %>% # fit model
  summary() %>% # get summary
  coef() # only coefficients
```

Output for the model. The last coefficient tells you that there is an interaction—the effect of the winner on happiness depends on how much the person likes the warriors:

```
                            Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                   0.05427454  0.2948804  0.1840561 8.541597e-01
winnerwarriors               -0.32370751  0.4136339 -0.7825942 4.348099e-01
like_warriors                -0.86373092  0.3134189 -2.7558355 6.406481e-03
winnerwarriors:like_warriors  1.81595432  0.4159198  4.3661165 2.045998e-05
```

And a plot, showing an interaction:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=like_warriors, y=happiness, group=winner, color=winner)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

[image]

You can see there that the *association* between liking the warriors and happiness *depends* on who wins. That is an interaction (this is synonymous with "moderation").

#### Question 2

Yes, you can have an interaction between two continuous variables. The math is exactly the same. Generally, what people will do is pick a few points on the moderator (usually, 1 standard deviation below the mean, the mean, and one standard deviation above the mean) to show the relationship between the IV and DV on. If there is an interaction, the relationship should be different depending on the level of the moderator.

I have yet another basketball example! I looked at the relationship between how many blocked shots someone had and their defensive rating (an overall measure of how good someone is at defense). However, I looked to see if this interacted with *year*, which is a continuous measure. There was a significant interaction:

[image]

Although both blocks and year were continuous measures. You can see that the relationship between blocks and defensive rating is stronger in 2016 than it was in 1989—an interaction between two continuous variables.

#### Question 3

Yes, you must include an interaction term when fitting the model. The interaction term is simply multiplying the two variables by one another. So if I wanted to see if `X` and `Z` had an interactive effect on `Y`, I would specify:

```
Y ~ X + Z + X * Z
```

Comment: Just another question.It means I need to bring the interaction of all variables into the model (for example y=x+z+m+d+x *y *m *d) and if I was nonsignificant, do i need to remove it from the model and just keep the simple model without interaction?

Comment: When you add interactions that are more than just two variables, you need to bring in all of the combinations of lower-order interactions. For instance, that shows a four-way interaction. You would need to include all of the possible three-way interactions, all of the possible two-way interactions, and all of the main effects. One of the best parts of using the `lm` function in R is that if you just type `y ~ x*y*m*d`, it fills in all of that for you.