# Significant interaction and not significant correlation

Tags: correlation, interaction

I am currently working on my master thesis and need help.

Basically, the correlation is not significant in most of the cases (except the one between the 2 DV).

Despite this, I got a significant interaction between the IV and Moderator using the PROCESS macro for SPSS.

My assumption is that the insignificant correlation is due to the fact that it does not take into account the influence of the Moderator (e.g. correlation between IV-DV). Respectively, in my case, one moderator influences the IV-DV relationship in a positive way and another in a totally opposite way. So I assume it cancels each other out and that's why there is not correlation.

What do you think about that and how can I prove it? Or better justify my reasoning?

I plotted the lines of the two-way interaction effects. It looks almost symmetrical. Would it be an argument to explain my reasoning that on average the correlation canceled each other out?

[image: [1]: http]

[image]

Comment: I think it would be easier to talk about this in terms of means and simple effects rather than correlations. A simple description is that your simple effects were in different directions resulting in strong evidence of an interaction (put F, df, and p value here)  and no evidence for a main effect.

Comment: Updated my answer since you posted your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with David Lane's comment that you should talk about these in terms of means and simple effects, not correlations. Did you manipulate the portrayal and the emotions of love or fear? If so, you are under selling your data by talking about it in terms of correlations instead of effects.

This is called a *crossover interaction*. There are no main effects, because the effects of the IV on the DV is opposite for each level of the moderator. I don't know what you mean by "prove" this, but you would report the *F* statistic and *p* value associated with both main effects, and then talk about the significant interaction.

You could then follow-up this discussion by talking about the simple main effects, which PROCESS Model 1 reports for you automatically. If you post the output from PROCESS, we can show you where those results are if you are stuck with that.

The main effect is pretty much just pretending the moderator doesn't exist—it *collapses* across both levels of the moderator. And since the relationship is positive in one condition and negative in the other, these balance out. [I describe an intuitive example of a crossover interaction in this CrossValidated post; see the basketball example with the graph that looks like yours.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284798/interaction-vs-association/284829#284829)

After looking at the PROCESS output:

When WPort is 0, then there is a positive, significant effect of ForLove on AadTOT, *p* = .0042. When WPort is 1, there is a negative, but not statistically significant, effect of ForLove on AadTOT, *p* = .0758. Those are the simple main effects.

Comment: That's right, I did manipulate the emotions and portrayal (2x2 between-subjects design).

Comment: Then yes, do not discuss it it in terms of correlation. The stats are the same (i.e., the stats don't know if you manipulated the factor or not), but treat it as main effects, interaction effects, and simple main effects (where simple main effects are the effects *within* a condition). Discuss the main effects, then the interaction, then the simple main effects.

Comment: Now it makes sense why I should not talk about the correl. 
I also thought that it is not relevant in my case as the effects are opposite and cancels each other out when we just look from the IV-DV perspective.

However I am still a bit confused in regards tot the main/simple effects.

Will  attach the Process output.

Comment: **Main effect:** The effect of the IV on DV, ignoring the influence of the Moderator. **Simple main effect:** The effect of the IV on the DV, *within* a level of the Moderator.